# IntelliJ Command Line Launcher for Multiple Windows

Tags: intellij-idea, command-line, launch, alfred

I just downloaded https://github.com/bchatard/jetbrains-alfred-workflow only to discover that it only works for the very first project you open.  I usually have a ton of different projects that I'm regularly cycling through, so it's a bit of a pain to always go through the whole `File...Open` process.

Does anyone potentially know a way around this?  I'm running OSX El Capitan 10.11.4 and IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.2 Build #IC-162.1628.40.